# Privacy Badger extension blocks iframe content using iframe-resizer

Tags: iframe-resizer

The Privacy Badger extension blocks content from any iframe running iframe-resizer.
The console warning is:
[iFrameSizer][Host page: xxx] IFrame has not responded within 5 seconds. Check iFrameResizer.contentWindow.js has been loaded in iFrame. This message can be ignored if everything is working, or you can set the warningTimeout option to a higher value or zero to suppress this warning.

Is there a way to test for this on the parent page and display a message to the visitor to disable the extension?